# Can we have name nodes in one cluster and data nodes in another cluster?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

For hadoop 2.0, can we have an architectural setup where all the name nodes are in one cluster and all the data nodes in another cluster?

Comment: Even if it's possible, does it even make sense to have separate cluster? Will NameNodes still operate without DataNodes? Will DataNodes still operate without NameNodes?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's possible.

Refer to [HDFS Federation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/Federation.html) article from Apache website.

**Multiple Namenodes/Namespaces**

> In order to scale the name service horizontally, federation uses multiple independent Namenodes/namespaces. The Namenodes are federated; the Namenodes are independent and do not require coordination with each other.

***The Datanodes are used as common storage for blocks by all the Namenodes***.

> Each Datanode registers with all the Namenodes in the cluster. Datanodes send periodic heartbeats and block reports. They also handle commands from the Namenodes.

[image]

Comment: This is Federation where NameNodes are independent of each other and DataNodes report to all the NameNodes. What the OP was asking is a Cluster of NameNodes (or possibly HA NameNodes) and a Cluster of DataNodes.